# How to get IUnknown from WDM driver CreateInstance

Tags: python, com, ctypes, iunknown

In documentation (C++ example)

```
LUnknown* pIUnknown = CreateInstance(slot);
```

I try this

```
>> import ctypes
>> print type(ctypes.cdll.lcomp.CreateInstance(0))
<type 'int'>
```

How to get IUNKNOWN and QueryInterface?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that accessing COM object with ctypes might be a bit difficult. I would recommend to have a look to win32com included in the windows extensions by Mark Hammond.

You can start with this tutorial : http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html

I hope it helps